# Where is this array value coming from?

Tags: c++, arrays, random

So I'm practicing coding before classes begin again and I wanted to create a random array of 10 integers and wanted to find which two numbers, when added together, equal greater than 100.

When I run the code below

```
int arr[9];

for(int i = 0; i<=9; i++){
    arr[i]=(rand()%100)+1;
    cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
}

cout<<endl;

for(int k = 0; k<=9; k++){
    for (int j = k+1; j<=9; j++){
        if((arr[k]+arr[j])>100){
            cout<<arr[k]<<" + "<<arr[j]<<" "<<"over 100"<<endl;
        }
        else{
            cout<<arr[k]<<" + "<<arr[j]<<" "<<"under 100"<<endl;
        }
    }
}


return 0;
```

I notice that the value of arr[9] is equal to one number but the program has another number for it.
For example: the array that's created is
**[42
68
35
1
70
25
79
59
63
65]**

but my output shows a 9 as arr[9]

42 + 68 over 100

42 + 35 under 100

42 + 1 under 100

42 + 70 over 100

42 + 25 under 100

42 + 79 over 100

42 + 59 over 100

42 + 63 over 100

**42 + 9 under 100**

(I'll just include the first loop to not make this any longer)

Where did my 65 go??

Where did the 9 come from??

Did I write something wrong??

Thanks

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i<=9; i++)` That's one iteration too many. The array has only 9 elements.

Comment: To be maybe brutally honest, the problem seems to be that you have missed a crucial part of your text-book, tutorial or class. Please go back to see what it says about array sizes and indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I notice that the value of arr[9] is equal to one number but the program has another number for it.

Counting in computers starts from `0` and ends at one number less than the total size. For `int arr[9]`

- the ninth index is `arr[8]`
- the 1st index is `arr[0]`
- the 2nd index is `arr[1]`

When you do `arr[9]`, you are crossing the boundary (accessing an element that's not in the range) which leads to undefined behaviour.

As a result, your loop should stop at `i < 9`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) // i < 9 now vs i <=9
```

The same changes need o be made to the loops below the first one.